# Change voice style by using setVoice(android.speech.tts.Voice)

Tags: android, google-text-to-speech

I need to change the voice style of user text to speech tts engine
below is my code

```
private TextToSpeech tts;
tts = new TextToSpeech(context, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
Voice voiceobj = new Voice("This is kirti for welcome you", Locale.getDefault(), 1, 1, false,
                     "This is");
            tts.setVoice(tts.getVoice());
}
```

I am using android Voice class as its added on API level 21
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/Voice.html

for Setvoice
() http://developer.android.com/reference/android/speech/tts/TextToSpeech.html#setVoice(android.speech.tts.Voice)

Comment: **1** - You misspelled `getVoices()`. **2** - I guess you must use it like `tts.setVoice(tts.getVoices(0));` (being 0 the first voice available?)

Comment: @DerGolem Thanks, but its not allowing me to adding integer arguments

Comment: What does it expect? A String? A Voice object?

Comment: I don't know. Just asking. I suppose that that method expects something to be passed to it.

Comment: ok, thanks but no solution till today, I expect some solution !!!

Answer (score 2):

This is the way to set the method, the name, contains the name of the voice.

```
 Voice voiceobj = new Voice("it-it-x-kda#male_2-local", 
     Locale.getDefault(), 1, 1, false, null);

 tts.setVoice(voiceobj);
 String text = "Ciao Daniel, come stai?";
 tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null,null);
```

Comment: requires at least api 21